# NodeJS canvas.createJPEGStream creates empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, stream, fabricjs

Hy
I'm trying to save my canvas to a file. After loading the canvas with loadFromJson(canvas) I try to create a JPEG stream and writing it to a file, but the result is just a black image. 
this is my code

```
var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(width, height);
canvas.loadFromJSON(page['canvasData'], functioN(){
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile);
    var stream = canvas.createJPEGStream({quality: 100});
    out.on('finish', seriesCallback);
    stream.pipe(out);
});
```

tried to insert an stream.on('error') call but nothing get's logged. I tried with toDataUrl and everything worked fine, so it shouldn't be a problem of the loadFromJson.
Any ideas? 
thank's

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry, I was just missing a canvas.renderAll(); after the loadFromJson. I'm leaving this here, just in case someone has the same problem